# Sound Cloud & Javascript: upload music from stream

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm very happy to know Sound Cloud provided API to upload music. Also they made a [pretty good doc](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading-files) on how to do that. But as they right mentioned - there is a problem

**Problem:** Javascript SDK hasn't access to file system. So

**Question:** *How to download music to Sound Cloud from JS stream?*

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to files by using a form with `<input type="file">` or the drag-and-drop api.

MDN has a lot of information about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications